# Error al generar un PDF en Python con win32com

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pdf

Estoy haciendo un script en Python que consiste en hacer unos filtros a un DataFrame en Pandas y luego ese DataDrame lo debo guardar en una hoja de un archivo Excel que ya está creado. Esto lo hago con xlwings para poder mantener los demás datos y hojas del archivo en cuestión usando las siguientes líneas:

```
wb = xw.Book(archivo_excel_solicitd)
ws = wb.sheets[sheet_name_rows]

start_row = 2
start_col = 1
ws.range((start_row, start_col)).options(index=False, header=False).value = df_filtrado

# Guardar el libro de trabajo con los datos agregados
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Luego de ello, ejecuto una función para ocultar unas filas en el archivo Excel. Por último, ejecuto una función para guardar una hoja del Excel a PDF con win32com pero allí me surge el siguiente error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\netap\Downloads\inclusiones\script.py", line 192, in <module>
    excel_to_pdf(archivo_excel_solicitd, sheet_name_to_pdf, f"/{ruta_carpeta}/{nombre_carpeta}.pdf")
  File "c:\Users\netap\Downloads\inclusiones\script.py", line 25, in excel_to_pdf
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(current_dir, excel_file))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\netap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 638, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks
```

No logro entender por qué me arroja este error si previamente los cierres del archivo se hacen exitosamente.

Aquí el código completo:

```
import os
from win32com import client
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import shutil

def excel_to_pdf(excel_file, sheet_name, pdf_output):
    """
    Convert an Excel file to a PDF.

    Args:
        excel_file (str): The path to the Excel file.
        sheet_name (str): The name of the Excel sheet to convert.
        pdf_output (str): The path to save the PDF file.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    # Crear una instancia de Excel
    excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    
    # Abrir el libro de Excel
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(current_dir, excel_file))
    
    # Seleccionar la hoja de Excel
    sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1]
    
    sheet.Visible = 1
    
    # Especificar el nombre del archivo PDF de salida
    pdf_output = os.path.abspath(pdf_output)
    
    # Guardar la hoja de Excel como PDF
    sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, os.path.join(current_dir, pdf_output))

    # Cerrar el libro de Excel y salir de la aplicación
    workbook.Close(False)
    excel.Quit()

def hide_empty_rows(excel_file, sheet_name, start_row, end_row):
    # Crear una instancia de Excel
    excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    
    # Abrir el libro de Excel
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(excel_file))
    
    # Seleccionar la hoja de Excel
    sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name]

    # Iterar sobre las filas desde start_row hasta end_row
    for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
        # Obtener el valor de la celda en la columna A y la fila actual
        cell_value = sheet.Cells(row, 1).Value

        # Verificar si la celda está vacía y ocultar o mostrar la fila en consecuencia
        if cell_value is None or cell_value == "":
            sheet.Rows(row).Hidden = True
        else:
            sheet.Rows(row).Hidden = False

    # Guardar el libro de Excel
    workbook.Save()

    # Cerrar el libro de Excel y salir de la aplicación
    workbook.Close(True)
    excel.Quit()

macros = "2anexo de inclusión MEDI firmas.xlsm"
macros_base = "base"
excel_file = "Plantilla - Anexo de inclusión MEDI firmas.xlsx"
sheet_name_rows = "Registros"
sheet_name_to_pdf = "Anexo"
start_row = 19
end_row = 34

base = pd.read_excel(macros, sheet_name=macros_base)

numero_solicitud = base['Número de Solicitud']
numero_solicitud = numero_solicitud.drop_duplicates()

ruta_base = './anexos'

for nombre_carpeta in numero_solicitud:
    ruta_carpeta = os.path.join(ruta_base, str(nombre_carpeta))

    # Crea la carpeta si no existe
    if not os.path.exists(ruta_carpeta):
        os.makedirs(ruta_carpeta)
    
    # Filtra el DataFrame base por el valor de 'nombre_carpeta'
    df_filtrado = base.loc[base['Número de Solicitud'] == nombre_carpeta]
    
    archivo_excel_solicitd = f"{nombre_carpeta}.xlsx"

    if not os.path.exists(archivo_excel_solicitd):
        shutil.copy(excel_file, archivo_excel_solicitd)

    wb = xw.Book(archivo_excel_solicitd)
    ws = wb.sheets[sheet_name_rows]

    start_row = 2
    start_col = 1
    ws.range((start_row, start_col)).options(index=False, header=False).value = df_filtrado

    # Guardar el libro de trabajo con los datos agregados
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
    
    hide_empty_rows(archivo_excel_solicitd, sheet_name_to_pdf, start_row, end_row)
    excel_to_pdf(archivo_excel_solicitd, sheet_name_to_pdf, f"/{ruta_carpeta}/{nombre_carpeta}.pdf")
```

He intentado tambien con openpyxl para poner los datos en la hoja de destino (por si xlwings deja una instancia abierta de Excel) pero me genera un error: AttributeError: property 'book' of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter:

```
reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")

book = load_workbook("Resultados.xlsx")

with pd.ExcelWriter("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets.update(dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets))

    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader)+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución final fue usar:

```
# Crear una instancia de Excel
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

# Abrir el libro de Excel
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(excel_file))
```

Y pasar excel y workbook a todas las funciones que requieren de la sesión para que solo use una sesión, valga la redundancia. Adicional, pasé los datos de pandas (que antes pasaba con xlwings) con win32com.